# Project structure for a simple WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following simple project, I described the functionality in the image.
I am exploring WPF, and I am not sure how should I structure my project. I can have folders:
Views, ViewModels and Models, but I am not really sure how to structure this project
in terms of Views, ViewModels and Models. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure MVVM, each `View` has one `ViewModel`, which can have multiple `Models`.

I can't really say what would be the best structure for you, but if I were you I would probably start off with something like this:

### Views

`MapView` - the view that displays the map

`MainView`- the view that displays the main window, ribbon and ect'

### ViewModels

`MainViewModel` - the logic for the `MainView` such as the logic of online/offline button

`MapViewModel` - the logic for `MapView`.

as far as Model's it is really hard to say because that is really specific to your application needs, which I don't know.

I'll probably consider another view for the ribbon if there will be different ribbons for different views ...

Hope this helps

Comment: So basically I don't have to constrain myself with anything. It is design stuff anyway. As you said, I could create a separate view and viewmodel for the ribbon. Hell, I could create a view and viewmodel for a button. My point is I should free myself and try stuff out, there is no right way here, agree?

Comment: @user2381422 Well, I wouldn't go as far as making a view/view model for a button, but I'll agree with you since I know you were kindding ;)